# Customizing ubuntu studio 13.04

Tags: 13.04, compiz, gtk, xfce, customization

I have recently switched from original ubuntu 12.10 to ubuntu studio 13.04. After some research I found out I could install compiz to this as well. I have to go to the terminal and run `compiz --replace` to get the changes I made to take effect, and even at that doesn't seem like all features work like work space cube. I also noticed that when I activated compiz through terminal my tool bars on all my windows goes away.

I heard I could install emerald windows manager to set windows and just add the command `emerald --replace` in compiz under window decoration. However when I search for emerald nothing comes up in synaptics or Ubuntu software center. I figure gnome tweak tools should let me set a theme to bring back my tool bars, but I am not positive this will work, or create more problems.

I guess ubuntu studio uses xfce desktop while original ubuntu used gtk. can I install gtk to ubuntu studio just like I did with original ubuntu 12.10 to set themes to fix this problem? has anyone else had the same problem with compiz on ubuntu studio with work space cube not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will want to add the PPA for the current compiz development.  While I realize this is not necessarily the most stable, it is significantly better than what comes in the repos:

https://launchpad.net/~smspillaz/+archive/compiz-experimental

I haven't tried this yet - it's my next step, but this is for emerald:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-install-emerald-in-ubuntu-1304.html